# Outdoor extension cable question

Tags: extension

I have an outdoor camera with a two prong plug. I need to run it about 18 feet to my outdoor outlet.

I’m trying to buy an extension cord on Amazon but everything that’s outdoor is three prong. So do I plug the two prong camera plug into the 3 prong extension plug?

Will that cause any problems if it rains? If you could tell me exactly what I need to buy, I’ll just get that online! Thank you.

Comment: You can add a picture of the camera and its plug to the question for better answers.  Is the two-prong plug a DC adapter?  That is, a plastic box that plugs into the wall with a thin wire and a little round plug that plugs into the camera?  If so you should extend *that*.

Comment: would you be asking this question if there was a power outlet next to the camera?

Comment: Extension cords (whether or not they are labeled "outdoor") are not designed to be left plugged in outside, the connections are not weatherproof. Best bet would be to move the receptacle (outlet) closer to the camera, using conduit, and utilizing an "in-use" outdoor cover.

Comment: Is it PoE capable?

Comment: Extension cords are also not designed (or code approved) for permanent use, which this will be.

Comment: First off, thanks for the downvotes. You guys are super nice! So based on every response I’ve gotten, it’s universally impossible to have an outdoor camera connected to an outdoor outlet, with an outdoor extension cable.  For some reason it feels like something is missing from that conclusion.  Is there anyone out there that might actually assist me with my question so that I can accomplish my goal? The outlet is properly made for outdoor use. And the camera is an outdoor camera. I just need something in between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No different from plugging that same camera into a 3 prong receptacle directly.

However, you should make sure that:

- the camera can handle being outside
- the connection between the camera plug and the extension cord should be protected from rain etc.

You may want to look into a camera that supports power over ethernet. Then you connect one low voltage cable and you don't need to rely on Wi-Fi.

Comment: Thank you. That was actually helpful. I’ll buy some electrical tape and wrap it around the connection.